# count and count unique in a single mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo aggregate query which calculates `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX` and `BLANK` counts of different keys.

```
db.getCollection('ReportTestProcess').aggregate([
   $group": {
                "_id":0,
                "Inititated_on_MIN": {
                    "$min": "$Inititated_on.v"
                },
                "Inititated_on_MAX": {
                    "$max": "$Inititated_on.v"
                },
                "Text_COUNT":{$sum:1},
                "Text_BLANK": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [
                            {
                                "$ifNull": [
                                    "$Inititated_on.v",
                                    false
                                ]
                            },
                            0,
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                }
}])
```

Now I want `UNIQUE_COUNT` of elements along with it. The only way I could think of doing it is to group based the fields but grouping will affect the results of `MIN`, `MAX` or `COUNT`

Comment: You can use _$addToSet_ (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) to get unique values.

Comment: where is the `_id` expression in the `$group` stage here? and what is the `Text` here?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Updated the _id and Text is some text field

Comment: You can use `$addToSet` here, `{ "UNIQUE_TEXT": { "$addToSet": "YOUR_FIELD" }}` and then use one `$project` stage to find the length of the `UNIQUE_TEXT` array or either use `$facet` aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$addToSet`

Sets always keep unique values. Your code should look like.

```
db.getCollection('ReportTestProcess').aggregate([
   $group": {
            "Inititated_on_MIN": {
                "$min": "$Inititated_on.v"
            },
            "Inititated_on_MAX": {
                "$max": "$Inititated_on.v"
            },
            "Text_COUNT":{$sum:1},
            "Text_UNIQUE": { $addToSet: "$Inititated_on.v" }
            "Text_BLANK": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$ifNull": [
                                "$Inititated_on.v",
                                false
                            ]
                        },
                        0,
                        1
                    ]
                }
            }
}])
```

Comment: Works Like a charm paired it up with a project stage and use `$size` to get the count